# Django view not receiving variables from post form

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am sending variables from one template to a view through a post form and then using them in the next template. But the variables are not present when it reaches the template.

Here is the JavaScript used in the first template. game2.html:

```
function clickFntn(clicked_id) {
{% autoescape off %}
  var clicked = document.getElementById(clicked_id).src;
  var clicked1 = clicked.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
  var clicked2 = clicked1.slice(0,-4);
  if (clicked2 == gv_common) {
    gv_set1_counter = gv_set1_counter + 1;
    var set1 = {{ set1 }};
    if (gv_set1_counter == 2) {
      var_user = "{{user}}";
      game_id = {{game.id}};
      var player_end_time = new Date();
      var play_time = parseInt((player_end_time-player_start_time)/1000);
      post("{% url 'game2_end' %}", {type:"first", user:var_user, time: play_time, id: game_id});
    }
{% endautoescape %}
};
function post(path, params, method) {
    method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.

    // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
    // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
    var form = document.getElementById("form1");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);

    for(var key in params) {
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
         }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

view.py:

```
def game2_end(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST.get("type") == "first":
            user_var = request.POST.get("user")
            id_var = int(request.POST.get("id"))
            game=get_object_or_404(mt_game, pk=id_var)
            if (request.user == game.f_player1):
                p1_time_var = int(request.POST.get("time"))
                p2_time_var = game.f_p2_play_time
                mt_game.objects.filter(pk=id_var).update(f_p1_play_time=2)
                return render(request, 'game2_end.html', {'user_var':user_var, 'id_var': id_var, 'p1_time_var':p1_time_var, 'p2_time_var':p2_time_var})
            elif (request.user == game.f_player2):
                p1_time_var = game.f_p1_play_time
                p2_time_var = int(request.POST.get("time"))
                mt_game.objects.filter(pk=id_var).update(f_p2_play_time=p2_time_var)
                return render(request, 'game2_end.html', {'user_var':user_var, 'id_var': id_var, 'p1_time_var':p2_time_var, 'p2_time_var':p1_time_var})
```

The second template file: game2_end.html

```
<p>Game id: {{id_var}}</p>
<p>User: {{user_var}} </p>
<p>Your Gameplay Duration: {{p1_time_var}} seconds </p>
<p>Opponent Gameplay Duration: {{p2_time_var}} seconds </p>
```

The browser output I get is:

```
Game id: 23

User: ""

Your Gameplay Duration: seconds

Opponent Gameplay Duration: seconds
```

All variables except `id_var` are missing.
I have checked if the variables are available in the first template just before the post request and they are. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out `request.user` was adding a trailing space to my username. Replaced it with `str(request.user).strip()` and it worked like a charm.